# Camera Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, getpicture

I'm trying to get a low quality image from the cordova camera plugin on phonegap, I'm passing the quality params. But whatever percentage I send I still get the full quality.

```
var options = {
  quality: 5,
  destinationType: 1,
  sourceType: 1,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
  correctOrientation: true
};
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
```

Comment: Check the file size to be sure you are not getting any difference in quality. Modern cameras can often have such a high resolution that quality differences can only be visually seen on larger screens. I.e. small phone screens may hide the quality loss.

Comment: Also check your phone capture quality

Comment: @Fido thanks for the tips. Somehow after I added 'allowEdit: true' ti worked.

Comment: if it's happening on iOS, it was a bug

Comment: @jcesarmobile I haven't actually tried on other devices, but it fixed on iOS.